# traveling and returning back to italy

Tags: visas, italy, albanian-citizens

I am Albanian and I have applied for the first residence permit in Italy . I want to go to Albania but can I return back to Italy again with the residence permit receipt?

Comment: @Hatef why don't you make that an answer, and please copy the crucial info from the link into the answer in case the link goes bad. Ping me and I will +1

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the receipt you receive from the post bank would suffice! As written in the website of the State Police, [here](http://poliziadistato.it/articolo/378-Immigrati_per_uscire_dall_Italia_basta_la_ricevuta_postale):

> Gli stranieri in attesa del rinnovo del permesso di soggiorno possono
>   uscire dall'Italia e rientrarci presentando solo la ricevuta delle
>   Poste italiane che attesta l'avvenuta presentazione della domanda di
>   rinnovo del loro permesso di soggiorno o della carta di soggiorno.

*English Translation:*

> Foreigners awaiting the renewal of the residence permit can leave
>   Italy and return by submitting only the receipt of the Italian Post
>   Office which proves the submission of the application for renewal of
>   their residence permit or residence card.

Comment: Beware that this receipt will probably _not_ be accepted for transit through another Schengen country on the way to Italy. That's probably not likely for Albania to Italy anyway -- but don't try to go overland which would take you through Slovenia.

Comment: @HenningMakholm true, however, I've seen few times people use it in transits, e.g. Tehran -> Milan via Istanbul - in Istanbul some agents would verify the validity of the receipt (could take few minutes) and then let you in. This might not apply to all airports though.

Comment: x @Hatef: Istanbul is not in a Schengen country!